# Phone stolen, got new phone & phone number, need old whatsapp CONTACTS back

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

so I have NO way to get my old sim card, my phone was stolen and I can't get my old contacts either. How can I change my new sim card number to my old one, within whatsapp? all I want is for my old Whatsapp contacts to be able to find me. I have a very important person that I need to contact and the only way is by that person seeing my profile back.

Help please,

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing of that is specific to Android, so you're much better off with WhatsApp support for that. Apart from which: Have you considered using our [search function](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[whatsapp-messenger]+new+phone) before asking? 77 related questions, [30 having answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[whatsapp-messenger]+new+phone+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 0):

Contact your provider to get the old number back. You can let them send a new simcard to you with the old number and block the old simcard. You don't have to buy a new one.